# Prevent React Router Link from automatically generating the path of the location

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

Maybe I'm missing something, but I'm stuck with React Router Link and the path it's generating on the other location than '/'. To put it simple, when I'm on home ('/'), everything's okay, but when I am on the location (for example) http://somedomain.com/posts/newest and use Link component like this:

`<Link to="/title-for-the-article">Link to the article</Link>`

Raw HTML **a** tag after the render looks like this (which is not what I want)

`<a href="/posts/title-for-the-article">Link to the article</a>`

How to prevent that path '/posts/' from being attached to every Link component? I just want to use the exact path that I passed through the "to" attribute. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `exact` param it only returns the exact path that match the url.

```
<Route exact path="/posts/title-for-the-article" component={Component} />

<Link to="/posts/title-for-the-article">Link to the article</Link>

// Location descriptor path to in string
<Link to={{ pathname: '/posts/title-for-the-article' }}/>
```

Comment: Perfect! With location descriptor it worked as a charm. :)